# Get notification on union of selected tag, along with intersection

Tags: discussion, tags, search, live-refresh

When I click on a tag [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) along with **newest** tab selected. It shows all the question related with that tag sorted by newest:

> [image: image showing selected tag]

It also gives me badge whenever new question with [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag arrives:

> [image: show badge that 4 new question arrived] .

Now if I click another tag, let's say [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) it show questions which contains both [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) and [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone):

> [image].

Question which only contain [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) or [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) will not be shown in this case (please correct me if I am wrong). Though this image says I am not:

> [image: image showing all <code>ios</code>, <code>iphone</code> and <code>ios+iphone</code>, notifications]

So if I want to answer the question which contains [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) or [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) tag, then I need to open 2 tabs, one with [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag  selected and another with [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) tag selected. Which leads to another problem. Problem of redundancy.

As if some question which contains both [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) and [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) tags, will repeat in both of the window.

Hence I propose an idea, what if we provide some solution which provide all new questions and there notification, arrived on both(or many) tags. Inside one window.

I tried my best to be clear. But please ask me I case of something is not clear.

Also let me know if it is already implemented, and I am not aware of that.

Comment: Try searching for `[ios] or [iphone]`?

Comment: @animuson So it was that easy :D. Thanks!